Component form and list on livewire update list when saving data
I have a question with Livewire, could anyone indicate any material on how to do this? Or someone can give a help

I have a form component, when saving I want to update the listing
Listing component should receive the update of the form data

Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/lordjack/f6406c7b865d493a3a7915451a494ece
However, by saving the data with the form, it does not update the listing. Being necessary to press the F5 key to make a refresh on the screen

As per my understanding, you have facing an issue of component re-render.
After submit the form data, your list view is not re-render with latest data..
Please try below,
in ItemsList.php
public $products;    
protected $listeners = ['products-refresh' => 'updateList'];

